# AttributeError 'Model' object has no attribute 'get_FOO_dispay'

Tags: django

Trying to run this code:

```
qs = Model.objects.all()
q = qs.get(id=1)
print(type(q))
print(q.field)
print(q.get_field_display())
```

returns

```
<class 'myapp.models.Model'>
FV
'Model' object has no attribute 'get_field_display'
```

Am I not using it correctly? Field is a choice field:

```
field = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=CHOICES,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Comment: Show your `models.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a spelling mistake here:

```
print(q.get_field_dispay())
```

It would be:

```
print(q.get_field_display())
```

Comment: My bad. But this typo was in the post, not in the console.

Comment: @Viktor what's your model name?

Comment: For the sake of this example ```Model```. It's not the syntax problem.